# Django 'int' object is not subscriptable shows while adding images to database

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I'm Inserting multiple images to database. I have saved the new Image name is `Dictonary`. But while inserting the data to table i'm getting ERROR : `'int' object is not subscriptable'`

I have searched everywhere but couldn't find solution.

Here is below how `Dictonary` looks like

```
    {
    "0" = {
        "blog_id" = "". 
        "blog_image_path" = "07-09-2018__17-54-152069weather.jpg". 
        "is_deleted" = 0
    }. 
    "1" = {
        "blog_id" = "". 
        "blog_image_path" = "07-09-2018__17-54-152069user.png". 
        "is_deleted" = 0
    }. 
    "2" = {
        "blog_id" = "". 
        "blog_image_path" = "07-09-2018__17-54-152069tick.png". 
        "is_deleted" = 0
    }
}
```

Now while adding the DB

```
for image in blog_images_data:
    blog_image_data = BlogImages(blog_id=int(blog_id), blog_image_path=image['blog_image_path'], is_deleted=int(image['is_deleted']))# I GET ERROR IN THIS LINE
    blog_image_data.save()
```

I have even changed the datatype to `INT` but still error persists.

Below is the Model Details

```
class BlogImages(models.Model):
blog_image_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
blog_image_path = models.TextField(null=True)
is_deleted = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0, editable=True)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'tbl_blog_images'
```

### THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: Your dictionary looks very strainge, normally the format is `{ key: value }`, not `{ key = value }`.

Comment: Furthermore it looks to me that `image` in your code is just an `int` (for example `42`, so then `image['blog_image_path']` indeed makes no sense, you iterated over the keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code the `for` loop **iterates over the keys of the dictionary**. So image is `0`, `1`, `2`, etc.

If this is indeed a dictionary (the syntax is not really correct), it should look like:

```
for blog_id, image in blog_images_data.items():
    blog_image_data = BlogImages(
        blog_id=int(blog_id),
        blog_image_path=image['blog_image_path'],
        is_deleted=int(image['is_deleted'])
    )
    blog_image_data.save()
```

So we iterate over *key-value* pairs with `.items()`, and do the processing with `image` being the subdictionary.

We can perform the creation of the object and saving it to the database in a single call with:

```
for blog_id, image in blog_images_data.items():
    blog_image_data = BlogImages.objects.create(
        blog_id=int(blog_id),
        blog_image_path=image['blog_image_path'],
        is_deleted=int(image['is_deleted'])
    )
```

> **Note**: normally models have *singlar* names, so `BlogImage`, instead of `BlogImages`.